# Create Pivot tables within a for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 70 plus sheets. Each sheet is created and named, and I put corresponding data into the worksheet using filters.  The data range has potential to change week to week.  I have written a vba program to do everything but create pivot tables within each worksheet using the unique filtered data.  ***My question is, how do I create a pivot table within each worksheet inside the for loop?  I have deducted that the problem in my code below is the source data section in the code.***  The data range for each tab will be different(columns stay same but number of rows will differ). ***Do I also need to rename the pivot tables as they iterate within the loop?***

```
Sub Ptloop()

dim x as long
dim SorceRange as Range
dim k as long
'start of first generated work sheet
x=4
'number of worksheets
k=75


Set SourceRange = Range("A4", ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If x <= k Then

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
   Sheets(x).SourceRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Sheets(x).Cells(4, 21), TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion _
   :=xlPivotTableVersion14
 x = x + 1
Else
Exit For
End If
Next Worksheet
End Sub
```

Comment: You will have to use Dynamic Range. Please refer this article [Create Dynamic Ranges with a Macro](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames03.html#Pivot)

Comment: Bring the `SourceRange` set inside the `For Loop` and qualify it to the `ws`. So `Set SourceRange = Worksheet.Range("A4", Worksheet.Range("A4")l.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))`. You can name each PT with `PivoTable & x`, if you want them to be different. It's not necessary though, if they are all on different sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things that may be throwing the code off, or have the potential too.

Please see the refactored code below for a cleaner, easier to maintain program.

```
Option Explicit 'this forces variable declaration and is a "must use" programming tool

Sub Ptloop()

Dim ws as Worksheet 'make sure to qualify the worksheet to a variable
                      'using `Worksheet` could be problematic since its a reserved word in Excel for the `Worksheet` object itself

Dim SourceRange as Range

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'if you have a chart or macro sheet in your workbook `Sheets` will produce an error, if you only need actual Worksheets, use that directly

    If ws.Index > 3 Then 'use the index property, you only want worksheets after sheet 3

       With ws 'work directly with the object and assignment parentage to all objects

           'set the range inside the loop to capture the data for that specific sheet
           Set SourceRange = .Range("A4", .Range("A4").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

           'ActiveWorkbook may or may not refer to the workbook you really want to work with .. ThisWorkbook refers to the book running the code
           ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SourceRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
               CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=.Cells(4, 21), TableName:="PivotTable" & ws.Index, DefaultVersion _
               :=xlPivotTableVersion14

       End With

   End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.  I had a lot of trouble with the SourceRange part.  Thank you for the tip using ws.Index. It greatly simplified my macro.  Thanks a ton.