# Loop through Worksheets to create Pivot Table from existing tables

Tags: excel, vba

I've searched and found [Create Pivot tables within a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312966/create-pivot-tables-within-a-for-loop), but haven't been able to get it to work.

I've got a workbook with 11 sheets and a table in each sheet, so I'd like to create a loop that will go through every sheet and create a pivot table next to the existing table.

I'm getting an "Invalid Procedure or argument " error for the Pivot Table code.

This code is probably far too simple, but here's my attempt:

```
sub PivotLoop()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set cache = Nothing
    Set PivT = Nothing

    With ws
                    
        On Error Resume Next             
        On Error GoTo 0
                   
        Set cache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                     SourceData:=Range("Table" & ws.Index), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

        Set PivT = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=cache, _
                    TableDestination:=Range("h2"), TableName:="PivotTable" & ws.Index)
                
    End With                  
Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work if anyone else wants to do it.

```
sub PivotTableLoop ()

Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim PivC As PivotCache
Dim PivT As PivotTable
Dim Table As ListObject
    
    For Each ws In WeeklyReport.Worksheets

    Set PivC = Nothing
    Set PivT = Nothing
    Set Table = Nothing
    
            On Error Resume Next
            '   Set PivotTable Cache
            Set PivC = WeeklyReport.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=ws.ListObjects(1), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

            '   Create the PivotTable
            Set PivT = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PivC, _
            TableDestination:=ws.Range("i2"), TableName:="PivotTable" & ws.Index)
            On Error GoTo 0
                    
                For Each PivT In ws.PivotTables
                    
                        PivT.PivotFields("day").Orientation = xlRowField
                        PivT.PivotFields("Competitor").Orientation = xlColumnField
                        PivT.AddDataField PivT.PivotFields("Sales"), xlSum
                        PivT.PivotFields("Sales").NumberFormat = "$0.00"
            
                Next PivT
                    
                    
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's done essentially like this. In your specific case, it will obviously be slightly different, depending on your sheet names, your ranges, whether you want counts, sums, averages, etc.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        ' don't touch a sheet with a specific name...if needed...
        If ws.Name <> "Master" Then

                ' now we want to build a pivot table
                Range("A1").Select
                Sheets.Add
                ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
                    "Sheet1!R1C1:R10C3", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
                    TableDestination:="Sheet5!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
                    :=xlPivotTableVersion15
                With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("field1")
                    .Orientation = xlRowField
                    .Position = 1
                End With
                With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("field2")
                    .Orientation = xlColumnField
                    .Position = 1
                End With
                ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("field3"), "Sum of field3", xlSum

        End If
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

It helps a lot if you turn on the Macro recorder and see what kind of code it produces and you click through the steps.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. The above doesn't work unfortunately. Looks like you have recorded the macro based on it referring to sheet1 and certain cells. I know how to build a pivot table with references to a specific sheet and table but the issue is with multiple sheets and tables. I think I need to declare an object but not sure how.